# Access to MySQL export XML

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, import, export

I have a database saved in access and need it to be transferred to a MySQL DB. I've done this before but for some reason it keeps transferring 0 rows. I'm exporting the table as a .XML then in MySQL i click import. It says

"Import has been successfully finished, 0 queries executed." any suggestions as to why?

Comment: One option is export to .csv file and import it from mysql using the command `load data from ...`

Comment: How is XML structured and how are you *importing* into MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exporting as excel and then saving the excel as a .csv worked.